# Use USB microphone (like a Snowball by Blue) to iPhone with Lightning cable

Tags: ios, usb, microphone, iphone

How to use a USB microphone like the [Snowball Ice by Blue](http://www.bluemic.com/products/snowball-ice/) with an iPhone with Lightning port (such as iPhone SE)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the [Lightning to USB Camera adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter) from Apple and then connect your microphone there.

Depending on the microphone, you could require an external USB power source. This is normally done by adding in a powered USB hub.

Note that this might not work with your specific microphone. It works with some USB microphones, but it is not really supported hardware by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Digital Inspiration has an article on [how to hook up a USB microphone to your iPhone](http://www.labnol.org/gadgets/connect-usb-mic-to-ipad/28683/):

> To get started, you would need a powered USB hub (look for the power adapter symbol in the description, also go for USB 3.0) and the lightning to USB adapter (remember, it’s the adapter and not the cable). Now connect the iPhone /iPad to the USB microphone through the USB hub as shown in the illustration above.
>
> 1. Plug one end of the Apple Lightning to USB adapter into the Lightning port of your iPhone or iPad and connect the other end to the powered USB hub through the supplied USB Type B cable.
> 2. Use the power adapter cord to connect the hub to the electrical outlet.
> 3. Connect the external USB microphone to one of the available ports on the hub using the same USB cable that you were previously using to connect the mic to the desktop computer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from digital inspiration worked perfectly with my blue snowball mic, all I did was connect one end of the supplied charging cable to my iPad & the other end to one of the rear USB ports of a cheapo USB 2.0 USB hub. Then I connected the blue snowball mic to another rear USB port on the hub. Finally I used an AC/DC adapter to connect the USB hub to the main power supply. Switched it on and voila! Red led turns on the snowball indicating there is power running to the device. Note that I first tried to connect the snowball to a front port on the USB hub but it didn't power on, I needed to use the rear ports to get it to work. I did not however need to buy any special adapters. One ordinary charger cable supplied with iPad/iPhone, 1 powered USB hub connected to 220v/110v main power supply. Too easy.